# Remove gap in wordpress posts in IE

Tags: wordpress, gaps-in-visuals

I'm using a modified version of Modern Clix by Rodrigo Galindez on my website, and I've encountered a problem with gaps on top of every one of my posts in IE.

The gap is the size of my left-hand sidebar and doesn't appear in firefox.

Ex.: http://martiningolf.dk/?page_id=273

If anyone knows how to solve this problem, It'd make me happy.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a float issue.

Your left column is set to float:left, but your right column (the post) isn't floating - it has a padding-left that pushes it over:

```
.nudge-2 { padding-left:15.2em }
```

IE hates padding.

You might try setting the right column to float:left as well. This will probably mean reducing its width from 80em to something narrower.

This may work:

```
.nudge-2 { padding-left:0em; }
.span-12 { float:left; width:64em;}
.post { border-top:1px solid #CCCCCC; clear:both; overflow:hidden; padding:1em 0 2em; width:90em; }
```

Good luck!